# How Can this code be adjusted to input and print a list of numbers?

Tags: java, arrays, input

I'm trying to create a program that allows the user to input numbers into a array called "numArray", however an exception is thrown once the user inputs numbers into array. How can this be fixed?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class ArrayNumList
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How many nums would you like to enter? ");
        int n = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter " + n + " nums");
        int[] numArray = new int[n];

        for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        {
            int index = in.nextInt();
            System.out.print(numArray[index]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `index` index if the user inserts a big enough number / negative number. Fix it by using the actual loop variable `i` like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    numArray[i] = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print(numArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you aren't storing your data anywhere in the array.

```
for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
{
    int index = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print(numArray[index]);
}
```

Every time you run through the array, you store your input into the variable `index`. From there, you try to display the value in your array at that index. This can lead to a few problems.

1) You haven't put your numbers into this array yet, so each value in the array is going to be 0. To fix this:

```
numArray[i] = in.nextInt();
```

2) If someone inputs a number that's bigger than the size of your array, you'll get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. I don't think you were trying to do it this way, but this is what your code is currently attempting to do.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 issues:-

1) Use i < n as you start from 0

2) Trying to add input value as index in the array.

3) Printing out the values while entering which create confusion for you better to do that in separate loop but I leave it to u or Better to use println instead of print

Try this:-

```
public static void main(String[]args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How many nums would you like to enter? ");
        int n = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter " + n + " nums");
        int[] numArray = new int[n];

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {

           numArray[i] = in.nextInt();
           System.out.println(numArray[i]);
        }

    }
```

Comment: How come you were able to type out such a long response, yet had to reduce "you" to "u"? This isn't texting... write full words.

Comment: There is no test of English grammar brother. I have provided the relevant information, it can be long or short depending upon the code.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly it should be `i<n` and not `i<=n` because `n` means the array length and `i` means the array index. The index starts from 0. For eg an array holds the values 1234, so the length is 4 but the index are 0,1,2,3. So the index is always one less than the array length. Also you have to store the input with the array index.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {

       numArray[i] = in.nextInt();
    }
```

And then later print it

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {

       System.out.println(numArray[i]);
    }
```